# NameError: uninitialized constant Mongoid::Relations after upgrading to mongoid 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am in the process of upgrading from rails 5.2 to 6.0. In that process, I also had to upgrade mongoid 6.0 to 7.0

Right after that, my rake scripts fail with this:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Mongoid::Relations
/mnt/src/lib/tasks/encrypted_fields_migration.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:660:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:660:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:660:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:518:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-6.0.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'
/mnt/src/rakefile:9:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is where the script fails:

```
    module Queries
      EMBEDDED_TYPES = [
        Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::Many,
        Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::One,
      ]
...
```

Looking for suggestions on how to go about troubleshooting this. (new to ruby)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out the `Mongoid::Relations` don't exist in mongoid 7 and they are apparently renamed to `Mongoid::Association::Embedded::EmbedMany/EmbedOne`